# How to make pie chart with optimized code?

Tags: python, charts

**What is the shortest and most optimal code for make pie chart?**
I want to make a pie chart using python. I tried to use the best library but most of them were long. Anyone have a shortcut?

Comment: Please add more details about what you've already done and what you want to get as a final result.

Comment: Optimizing code is ideally the last thing done when developing software. I suggest that you first write some code that does it anyway you can figure-out, then, if it's too slow, try to speed up the parts where it's spending most of it its time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, your question isn't really answerable, shy of someone writing an entire program for you. Since StackOverflow is not a code writing service, these questions are considered off topic. After reading the links above, please edit your question to include your attempts so far, and what precise problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
percent = [ x, y, z]
colour = [blue, green, red]
label = [name1, name2, name3]
plt.pie(percent , labels=label ,colors=colour)
plt.show()


#The sum of the values ​​of x,y,z must be 100 for 100%
```